# Blazor not working in Chrome but works in Edge

Tags: google-chrome, blazor, blazor-client-side

I was following the "[Get started with ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)" example but I get the following error when using the Chrome Browser:

> An unhandled error has occurred.

When using the Edge everything was ok.
Why this is happening?

Comment: To confirm, is this an exception on the C# side? What does the inner exception say?

Comment: I get no exception in the C# side. Just an error in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved possibly by Chrome actualization.
Now I am using the 79.0.3945.88 version, everything seems ok.

Comment: Weird, I'm having just the opposite result. Perfectly fine before tonight. Now I find Chrome always reports "An unhandled exception has occurred", with no errors in the console, and the page loads fine in IE. Double checked, I'm on 79.0.3945.88. 

I commented out all of the code in my app and rebooted, no dice.